# Get Control by URL

Tags: asp.net, url, webforms, request, controls

I'm currently on my first asp.net WebForms Site. To display different Sites I'm loading a control into a Placeholder in my masterpage.

example: `UserControl uc = this.LoadControl("~/controls/home.ascx") as UserControl;`

this goes over my `default.aspx` codebehind file. I'm now struggeling with fill in another control based on the URL. I know that you can get for example an ID (if `my-domain.com/default.aspx?id=1` then show control blabla) but is it possible that I read out the URL and instead of the ID a string? for examples:

```
my-domain.com/home -> this goes over my default.aspx, but shows de home controller 

my-domain.com/contact-> this goes over my default.aspx, but shows de contact controller
```

Can I check if it's `"/home"` and then show the home-control?

Has anyone an idea, how I could solve this problem?

Thanks guys :)

Here are a few code snippets:

**masterpage.master:**

```
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="content" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="myproject._default" %>
```

**default.aspx.cs:**

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentPlaceHolder content = this.Master.FindControl("content") as ContentPlaceHolder;
        displayControl(content);
    }

    private void displayControl(ContentPlaceHolder content)
    {

        UserControl uc = this.LoadControl("~/controls/home.ascx") as UserControl;

        if ((content != null) && (uc != null))
        {
            content.Controls.Add(uc);
        }            
    }
}
```

**home.ascx:**

```
my HTML-Page
```

My folders are in the following structure:

- css
- img
- javascript
- App_Data
- bin
- obj
- controls

  - home.aspx
  - contact.aspx   ... etc.
- default.aspx (with the code behind file .cs)
- masterpage.master
- misc: web.config and other files and folders...

Comment: I dont think this is possible. you can use query string to resolve this.. I can help you with querystring if you want

Comment: @Nitin Alapati
sure why not. I'm just looking for a good way to bind the controls nicely

Answer (score 0):

If you want your site to go from domain.com/default.aspx?id=1 to domain.com/home, or domain.com/login you need to enable Friendly URLs and setup a route in your WebForms.

Scott Hanselman has a walk-through at the following link...

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx